# Standard Behavior Of An Empty Macro Preceding A Preprocessing Directive

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

Take, for example, the following:

```
#define FOO
FOO #define BAR 1
BAR
```

What should, according to each of the ANSI C and C99 standards, be the preprocessed output of the above code?

It seems to me that this should be evaluated to `1`; however, running the above example through both `gcc -E` and `clang -E` produces the following:

```
    #define BAR 1
BAR
```

Comment: `#` should be the first non-space character in a line with directive, otherwise it gets ignored

Comment: @qrdl: it does not get ignored: it will produce an error because `#` is not a valid token after preprocessing.

Comment: @rici Obviously compiler will complain about it, but OP is talking just about CPP here, and CPP ignores it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The draft standard "ISO/IEC 9899:201x Committee Draft — April 12, 2011 N1570" section 6.10 actually contains an example of this:

> EXAMPLE In:
>
> ```
> #define EMPTY 
> EMPTY # include <file.h>
> ```
>
> the sequence of preprocessing tokens on the second line is not a preprocessing directive, because it does not begin with a # at the start of translation phase 4, even though it will do so after the macro EMPTY has been replaced.

It tells us that "... the second line is **not** a preprocessing directive ..."

So for your code

```
FOO #define BAR 1
```

is **not** a preprocessing directive meaning that only FOO will be replaced and BAR will **not** be defined. Consequently the output of the preprocessor is:

```
 #define BAR 1
BAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid

ISO/IEC 9899:2011, Section 6.10 Preprocessing directives:

> A preprocessing directive consists of a sequence of preprocessing
>   tokens that satisfies the following constraints: **The first token in
>   the sequence is a # preprocessing token** that (at the start of
>   translation phase 4) is either the first character in the source file
>   (optionally after white space containing no new-line characters) or
>   that follows white space containing at least one new-line character.

Answer (score 0):

This example actually occurs in the Standard (C17 6.10/8):

> EXAMPLE In:
>
> ```
> #define EMPTY
> EMPTY # include <file.h>
> ```
>
> the sequence of preprocessing tokens on the second line is not a preprocessing directive, because it does not begin with a `#` at the start of translation phase 4, even though it will do so after the macro `EMPTY` has been replaced.

So the output you see from `gcc -E` is correct.  (Note: the amount of whitespace here is not significant  , at that stage of translation the program has been translated to a sequence of *preprocessing tokens*; the different amounts of whitespace in the output is just an artefact of how `gcc -E` works).

Comment: Thank you as well, but, unfortunately, I can only accept one answer, and 4386427 was too quick. :)